# how to find string in html tag and replace using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I do not know how to find a string in the html tag and replace it with another one.
I will show it on an example.

I have something like that

```
<a class="test" data-value="/content/dam/tetris-templating/framework/svg/ic-editorial-07.svg"></a>
```

And I would like to get such an effect

```
<a class="test"> <img-src="/content/dam/tetris-templating/framework/svg/ic-editorial-07.svg"></a>
```

Does anyone have any idea? I'm sorry for my level of English.

Answer (score 4):

You can first `append` the `img` and then remove the attribute `data-value`.

See the code below:

```js
$("a").append(function(){
  return '<img src="'+$(this).attr("data-value")+'">';
}).removeAttr("data-value")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test" data-value="/content/dam/tetris-templating/framework/svg/ic-editorial-07.svg"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are new in `JavaScript` and/or `jQuery`, I've made a step-by-step example of a solution:

```
// create a pointer to your anchor
var $yourAnchor = $('.test')

// copy data attribute
var $hdata = $yourAnchor.data('value');

// remove attribute
$yourAnchor.removeAttr('data-value');

// insert html
$yourAnchor.html('<img src="' + $hdata + '">');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// If It has multiple hyperlink tag then
$('a').each(function(){
        if($(this).data('value')!=undefined){
            $(this).append(function(){
              return '<img src="'+$(this).attr("data-value")+'">';
            }).removeAttr("data-value");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test" data-value="/content/dam/tetris-templating/framework/svg/ic-editorial-07.svg"></a>
```